# One video not playing on WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview, urlrequest

In a small iOS app showing a website I use this code:

```
    var webView:WKWebView!
    ......

    let theURL = URL(string: "https://www.example.moon"),
    theRequest = URLRequest(url: theURL!),
    webView = WKWebView(frame: myWebFrame)

    webViewAL.load(theRequest)
    view.addSubview(webViewAL)
    ......
```

It works, but there is one small problem.

The first video on the site does not play and a message shows up, displaying:

```
Error loading media: File could not be played
```

But the following videos play without any apparent problem.

And on Safari all videos play normally.

What is the issue here? And why doesn't it work?

The video not playing seems to be a Flash Player file.

Comment: "The video not playing seems to be a Flash Player file." You answered the question yourself. iOS does not support Flash.

Comment: OK. So there is no way I can properly show this wesite from within an iOS app?